# Apache wont start, port 80 in use by a system process, found baiduspider

Tags: apache-http-server, process, port, xampp, robots.txt

Ok so I have uninstalled IIS on my windows server and decided to try Xampp to host my domains. Port 80 is in use and I have tried all of the fixes that I have came across for the past 2 days. I was in need of figuring out what is using process id 4 on my server which is a system process (NT Kernel & System). That doesnt tell me much and as I said, W3 publishing service is not running and neither is web deployment or MSSql logging.

I downloaded TCPLogView off of a nirsoft and let it run. For 20 minutes the only thing showing on port 80 (on the local end) with process id of 4 is a chinese robots.txt called baiduspider. The Remote hostname for this spider is baiduspider-123-125-71-111.crawl.baidu.com and in 20 minutes it has appeared 6 times using port 80.

This has got to be what is keeping me from starting APache on port 80 but I have no idea how to get rid of it or set it to another port. (not apache, the spider) IIS is uninstalled but my old sites are still in their folders. Any help on this? Thanks for reading!

Here is the log file from TCPLogView:

```
==================================================
Event Time        : 5/1/2015 10:07:56 PM
Event Type        : Open
Local Address     : 192.168.122.100
Remote Address    : 123.125.71.111
Remote Host Name  : baiduspider-123-125-71-111.crawl.baidu.com
Local Port        : 80
Remote Port       : 51636
Process ID        : 4
Process Name      : 
Process Path      : 
Remote IP Country : 
==================================================
```

Comment: Did you try netstat to identify the process using port 80?

Comment: Yes, that is how I found it to be NT Kernel & System which is a system process. It is using port 80 and TCPLogView is the only program thus far to further identify that it is the baiduspider bot from Beijing, China

Comment: What does "it is the baiduspider bot" mean, though? Does it mean NT System is running a Baidu crawler (that's how I'm reading it), or that the server is periodically being queried by a Baidu spider?

Comment: alright,, netstat and other programs identify local port 80 as process id 4. The remote port is 51636. Process id #4 is the system process. The TCPLogView program identifies process id #4 on local port 80 as the baiduspider (query) I am not certain this is just a query every 5-10 minutes or if this is keeping port 80 open which is in turn blocking me from starting apache. I have literally tried every single fix that has worked for others with similar situation and nothing is working, so this is where I am at now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I guess you'll just have to block the IP and restart your server.

Comment: Doing some more research, someone mentioned after they uninstalled IIS from their server, Windows continued to keep port 80 open for some unknown reason. So is there a way to change IIS port even though it is uninstalled? Or I guess I could reinstall IIS and change its port then uninstall it? Man this is annoying

Comment: baiduspider is simply the remote host that happened to connect to whatever server you have running locally listening on port 80.  They have nothing to do with the fact that you have something listening on port 80, which means apache can't do that.

Comment: The thing is, I have uninstalled IIS and all of its features in server manager, restarted multiple times and many other things. I have no webserver currently running

Comment: what about branchcache?

Comment: omg, I certainly do have branch cache installed, (im a newbie and a student) Let me check that out really quick.

Comment: 11:10:23 PM  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open          process" with PID 4!11:10:23 PM  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:10:23 PM  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:10:23 PM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port I thought for sure that would of been the issue but I uninstalled, then restarted server and problem still exists

Comment: OK, here is the latest! FIrst, THANK YOU RICHIE FRAME! He asked about Branch Cache and I uninstalled it and it did not fix it. About an hour later, I discovered Branch Cache was still showing up in Services. I am SURE I removed it but apparently not. Upon removal the 2nd time and a restart, IT WORKS! No more port 80 hysteria. Man I am so happy and grateful for the superuser community. Please Make that an answer so that I may mark it because after 2 days and about 15 hours total of trying to fix this, I never once ran across a suggestion to uninstall Branchcache! Thanks again all who helped.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP solved problem in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Branch Cache which was using port 80. Hope this helps others.